# how to get bash prompt on login

Tags: shell

When I connect to a remote machine using SSH, by default it is not on the bash prompt. To get the bash prompt by default on login I did as below by creating a .cshrc file in my home directory:

```
if ($?prompt) then
        setenv SHELL /bin/bash
        exec $SHELL -login
endif
```

It works well and I am getting the bash shell but I have another file as .bashrc in my home directory which gets executed when I run bash explicitly. I have done lot of customization in this file as per my requirements. Is it possible to get my .bashrc executed somehow from .cshrc or some other way?

For example I need to go connect to host B from host A, I do this:

> From A -> ssh B

This brings up host B but not with a bash prompt. To get a bash prompt I  created .cshrc as mentioned above but my above code snippet does not call my .bashrc script.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running [chsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) on the remote system?  It will change the default shell for your login account.

Answer (score 0):

To set the login shell of a user you have to modify your /etc/passwd file, field number 7:

```
dino:x:1002:1002::/home/dino:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Note that many systems do not use `/etc/passwd` these days.

Comment: I checked my user name is not in /etc/passwd. I guess the user is network user. In case if I don't want to use /etc/passwd, is there anyother way to achieve the same

Comment: @Paul R All modern unix/linux/unix_like systems support passwd/shadow, they give you the possibility to add support for PAM,LDAP,NIS and the like... but /etc/passwd is ok too

Comment: @user419534 have you checked on your remote host (HOST B in your case?)

Comment: Yes I checked on both remote and client host. The user does not exits in /etc/passwd

Comment: @Paul R the chsh command only works with /etc/passwd local authentication

Comment: @dAm2K: that's not true - for example Mac OS X does not use `/etc/passwd` for users. Also `chsh` works with other types of database, e.g. Open Directory.

Comment: @Paul R true but not 100%... it's used on single user mode

Comment: @dAm2K: so when you say "All modern unix/linux/unix_like systems support passwd/shadow" above, this is really not true.

Comment: IMHO MacOS is not a modern unix :-)